# Type hints for class decorator

Tags: python, mypy

I have a class decorator which removes one method and adds another to a class.

How could I provide type hints for that? I've obviously tried to research this myself, to no avail.

Most people claim this requires an intersection type. Is there any recommended solution? Something I'm missing?

Example code:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def do_check(self) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError

def decorator(clazz: type[MyProtocol]) -> ???:
    do_check: Callable[[MyProtocol], bool] = getattr(clazz, "do_check")

    def do_assert(self: MyProtocol) -> None:
        assert do_check(self)

    delattr(clazz, "do_check")
    setattr(clazz, "do_assert", do_assert)
    
    return clazz

@decorator
class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    def do_check(self) -> bool:
        return False

mc = MyClass()
mc.do_check() # hints as if exists, but doesn't
mc.do_assert() # no hints, but works
```

I guess what I'm looking for is the correct return type for `decorator`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to express dynamic changes to a type

Comment: `hints as if exists, but doesn't` based on your implementation, it does exist - calling `delattr` will just expose the parent method (`MyProtocol`'s `do_check`). If you run your code, it raises `NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type annotation which can do what you want. Even with intersection types, there won't be a way to express the action of deleting an attribute - the best you can do is making an intersection with a type which overrides `do_check` with some kind of unusable [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

What you're asking for can be instead done with a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html). The result can look like this after a basic implementation:

```py
from package.decorator_module import MyProtocol, decorator

@decorator
class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    def do_check(self) -> bool:
        return False
```

```
>>> mc = MyClass()  # mypy: Cannot instantiate abstract class "MyClass" with abstract attribute "do_check" [abstract]
>>> mc.do_check()   # raises `NotImplementedError` at runtime
>>> mc.do_assert()  # OK
```

Note that `mc.do_check` exists but is detected to be an abstract method by the plugin. This matches the runtime implementation, as `delattr` deleting `MyClass.do_check` merely exposes the parent `MyProtocol.do_check` instead, and non-overridden methods on a `typing.Protocol` are abstract methods and you can't instantiate the class without overriding them.

---

Here's a basic implementation. Use the following directory structure:

```
project/
  mypy.ini
  mypy_plugin.py
  test.py
  package/
    __init__.py
    decorator_module.py
```

Contents of `mypy.ini`

```ini
[mypy]
plugins = mypy_plugin.py
```

Contents of `mypy_plugin.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

import mypy.plugin
import mypy.plugins.common
import mypy.types

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    import mypy.nodes

def plugin(version: str) -> type[DecoratorPlugin]:
    return DecoratorPlugin

class DecoratorPlugin(mypy.plugin.Plugin):

    # See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#current-list-of-plugin-hooks
    # Since this is a class definition modification with a class decorator
    # and the class body should have been semantically analysed by the time
    # the class definition is to be manipulated, we choose
    # `get_class_decorator_hook_2`
    def get_class_decorator_hook_2(
        self, fullname: str
    ) -> cx.Callable[[mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext], bool] | None:
        if fullname == "package.decorator_module.decorator":
            return class_decorator_hook
        return None

def class_decorator_hook(ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext) -> bool:
    mypy.plugins.common.add_method_to_class(
        ctx.api,
        cls=ctx.cls,
        name="do_assert",
        args=[],  # Instance method with (1 - number of bound params) arguments, i.e. 0 arguments
        return_type=mypy.types.NoneType(),
        self_type=ctx.api.named_type(ctx.cls.fullname),
    )
    del ctx.cls.info.names["do_check"]  # Remove `do_check` from the class
    return True  # Returns whether class is fully defined or needs another round of semantic analysis
```

Contents of `test.py`

```py
from package.decorator_module import MyProtocol, decorator

@decorator
class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    def do_check(self) -> bool:
        return False

mc = MyClass()  # mypy: Cannot instantiate abstract class "MyClass" with abstract attribute "do_check" [abstract]
mc.do_check()   # raises `NotImplementedError` at runtime
mc.do_assert()  # OK
```

Contents of `package/decorator_module.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    _T = t.TypeVar("_T")

class MyProtocol(t.Protocol):
    def do_check(self) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError

# The type annotations here don't mean anything for the mypy plugin,
# which does its own magic when it sees `@package.decorator_module.decorator`.
def decorator(clazz: type[_T]) -> type[_T]:

    do_check: cx.Callable[[_T], bool] = getattr(clazz, "do_check")

    def do_assert(self: _T) -> None:
        assert do_check(self)

    delattr(clazz, "do_check")
    setattr(clazz, "do_assert", do_assert)

    return clazz
```